# Why is creating a new thread more expensive than keeping them idle?

Tags: .net, multithreading

ThreadPool keeps thread idle instead of creating and tearing them down, not all the time though based on how many threads it has a given time.

Even though I don't know the whole process during a thread creation and destruction, why is more expensive than having threads idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, because put simply, an idle thread isn't doing *anything*. It's just waiting around for work to do. Creating a thread involves allocating memory, load balancing...all kinds of stuff behind the scenes.

Comment: But it does still hold memory, overhead etc.

Comment: @Tarik well, yeah, but I was assuming the OP meant expensive only in the sense of computation time. edit - lol, you're the OP. Well then yes, you are correct

Comment: but when you compare the memory/physical overhead to the computation time, it's nothing. The default max number of threads is something like 1250 total threads per cpu, so its not like they're usually very limited. But when the threadpool sees that it's running low, it'll free up idle threads as it sees fit. So keeping them open is the closest thing to the best of both worlds

Comment: @Tarik Usually how efficient you are at doing work is much more important than how efficient you are when you don't have any work to do.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a managed thread a lot of stuff happens. Obviously both the native and the managed data structures for the thread are created. Furthermore, managed threads commits their entire 1 MB stack space and additional per thread data structures are allocated. In short this is a very expensive allocation.

By keeping threads around and reusing them (e.g. via the thread pool) this cost is amortized. That being said you still don't want to have an excessive number of threads just hanging around, cause they do take up resources even when idle. Consequently the thread pool will terminate idle threads periodically to reclaim resources.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because idle threads don't do anything.

Creating a thread performs a bunch of work (allocating memory, creating the data structures necessary to manage the thread, etc.).  All of that work is done once for a pooled thread, instead of performing it once each time there's work for a thread.